# Minted Crowdsale vs Non Minted Crowdsale

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20, ico, openzeppelin-contracts

I am exploring [openzeppelinr-solidity](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity) smart contracts for Initial Coin Offering(ICO). There are two options available for a token smart contract one is to have hardcoded total supply tokens or mint a new token every time investor purchases a token.

Is it necessary that token must be mintable for a minted crowd sale?

What if my token is mintable but my crowd sale is non-minted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's about compatibility.

With a fixed-supply token, the deployer gets the supply initially and then can send an allowance to a crowdsale contract which will then sell them from inventory.

With a minted token, the sale contract calls the tokens `mint()` function with each sale to create the needed tokens on-the-fly.

If you mix up incompatible types, you could have a mintable crowdsale calling a non-existent `mint` function in the token contract. This strikes me as the obvious reason to have two variants - either you do or you don't want that step.

If I'm not mistaken, you can use a mintable token with an allowance-style sale. In that case, the `minter` would occasionally mint more tokens and send them to the crowdsale.

In any case, test your implementation thoroughly. It's a best practice to publish a code audit publicly so your buyers have some assurance that there is no oversight in the finished product.

Hope it helps.